# Accessing Code inside $(function () { ... })

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, web-controls

I have a .NET web control that includes some JavaScript structured something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doSomethingImportant() {
        // Do something important here...
    }

    $(function () {

        // A bunch of JavaScript/jQuery code here...

    });

</script>
```

The `doSomethingImportant()` function is placed outside of my `$(function() { ... })` block so it can be called from JavaScript on the page that hosts my web control.

But I would like this function to be able to access some code within the `$(function() { ... })` block. Is this possible? Is there a better way to structure this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add a code on window object in the jquery function you can call it from the outer function.

e.g.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    function doSomethingImportant() {
        // Do something important here...
       window.myfunc();
    }

    $(function () {

        // A bunch of JavaScript/jQuery code here...

      window.myfunc = function(){
      }

    });

</script>
```